torsion free locus of a quasi-coherent sheaf
If $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf on a Noetherian scheme $X$, does the torsion free locus $U=\{ p\in X \mid \mathcal{F}_p \text{ is torsion free}\}$ an open subset of $X$?
EDIT: Thank Sasha for pointing out a counter-example. What about the coherent case? I believe the open neighborhood can be found after a finite (guaranteed by the coherent condition) sequence of localizations, but I can't make it explicit.

Consider, for example $F = \oplus_{p \in S} \mathcal{O}_p$, where $S$ is an infinite set of closed points of $X$.

If $F$ is coherent, its double dual $F^{\vee\vee}$ is torsion free. Furthermore, the subsheaf
$$
T(F) := \mathrm{Ker}(F \to F^{\vee\vee}) \subset F
$$
is torsion, and the sheaf
$$
F/T(F) = \mathrm{Im}(F \to F^{\vee\vee}) \subset F^{\vee\vee}
$$
is torsion free. Thus, $U$ is the complement of the support of $T(F)$, and since $T(F)$ is coherent, $U$ is open.
